# waiting until two values have changed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two form fields and would like to post those values using jquery only when both have a value. I have tried this but there must be a better way. I think this way could lead to errors

```
$('#RFID').change(function(e){          

    if($(this).val() != '' && $('#STATION_ID').val() != ''){                

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a particularly bad approach. It could be cleaned up a little though.  I would go with something like this:

```
var $fields = $('#RFID, #STATION_ID').change(function(e) {
    if ($fields[0].val() && $fields[1].val()) {
        // post it
    }
});
```

---

Edit: The code above was assuming you wanted to post as soon as you had both values. Looking at your question again, I may have read it wrong. If you simply want to prevent the form from posting unless you have both values, you would really want this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    if (!$fields[0].val() || !$fields[1].val()) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Althought i always thought it was best practice to test the length of the field with jQuery like this `if($fields[0].val().length > 0)`. :)

Comment: You can do that if you want, but `.val()` always returns a string, so it will be "truthy" in all cases if there's a value present.

Comment: Im trying to post the form values as soon as both have been filled out

Comment: Cool, so the first snippet would be what you want then. Just do something like `$(this).closest('form').submit()` where it says `// post it`.

Comment: can you call $fields from the line you are declaring it in? im getting an error

Comment: What error? And yes, `$fields` will be defined as soon as the `change` handler is registered, and far before the change handler is actually invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the same check before making the post:

```
if ($.trim($('#RFID').val()) != '' && $.trim($('#STATION_ID').val()) != '') {
    // do post
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably would assign an on change handler across all fields that could generate an auto submit of the form.

Perhaps adding a class against each field that could participate in a auto submit.

Little more code I know but sets the intent and collects the validation all in one place.

Hope it helps.

```
$('.auto-submit').change(function(e) {
  // collect all the auto submit fields and make sure they are not empty
  for( field in $('.auto-submit') )
     if( field.val() == '' ) return;   // all fields not there
  }
  // do form submit here
} );
```